# Minecraft plugin death teleportation

Tags: javascript, java, plugins, minecraft

I am coding a Minecraft plugin, the listener I am trying to code is when a player dies, it sends a message and teleports the player to a location. Here is my code. Thanks!

For some reason it doesn't teleport the player.

```
Location loc = new Location(Bukkit.getWorld("world"), -16.5, 67, -22.5, 0, 0);
player.teleport(loc);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been having the same issue for awhile. A work around I found was to use
the PlayerRespawnEvent where you can use the setRespawnLocation method to "teleport" them to that location.

something like this

```
@EventHandler
    public void onRespawn(PlayerRespawnEvent event) {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        event.setRespawnLocation(your location here);
        player.sendMessage("you respawned");
    }
```